# Windows user profile path folders

Tags: .net, windows

Can anyone describe how to get the following folders in screenshot in DotNet and what these folder are for? Below in the text described as "Missed" in Dotnet namespace.

[image: User folder Windows Explorer]

I only can get the following folders by  `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories`

.

**PROPERTY**....**PURPOSE**

**AllUsersApplicationData**

> The directory where applications should store settings for all users
>   (typically, something like
>   C:\ProgramData\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\1.0.0.0).

**CurrentUserApplicationData**

> The directory where applications should store settings for the current
>   user (typically, something like
>   C:\Users\PeterBlue\AppData\Roaming\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\1.0.0.0).

**Desktop**

> The current user's desktop directory (typically,
>   C:\Users\PeterBlue\Desktop).

**MyDocuments**

> The current user's My Documents directory (typically,
>   C:\Users\PeterBlue\Documents).

**MyMusic**

> The current user's My Music directory (typically,
>   C:\Users\PeterBlue\Music).

**MyPictures**

> The current user's My Pictures directory (typically,
>   C:\Users\PeterBlue\Pictures).

**ProgramFiles**

> The Program Files directory (typically, C:\Program Files).

**Programs**

> The current user's Programs directory (typically,
>   C:\Users\PeterBlue\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start
>   Menu\Programs).

**Temp**

> The current user's temporary directory (typically,
>   C:\Users\PeterBlue\AppData\Local\Temp).

**Missed** in DotNet namespace and missed information:

- Administrator
- Default
- Default User (why is there a key sign and how to get access?)
- user

  .

*** Own Solution ***

My own solution in getting out of the folder issue is to use use commandline `cmd` with `Dir /ah` [image: All users directory]
ex: Instead of "C:\Users\All Users"  now we can see the real folder is "C:\Users\Public\Documents" which is reachable throught `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments)`

Comment: Please complete the "Missed" item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note you should not use those profile folders to guess anything that you can retrieve from Environment.GetFolderPath. Anything you can get from there can be changed by SHSetFolderPath or some other tool. The supported way to retrieve those folders are documented already (Environment.GetFolderPath, SHGetFolderPath etc)

- Administrator/*user*: default location for profile of the user named Administrator/*user*. Can be retrieved via [GetUserProfileDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a user token.
- Default: default location of the template user's profile, which is used when creating a new user, can be retried by [GetDefaultUserProfileDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Default User : Some OEMs may create this folder by mistake. Possibly a leftover from code carelessly written for XP where the default user profile is stored in [GetProfilesDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762278%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)\Default User. Customization made to this folder has no effect unless the default user profile directory is changed by [SysPrep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysprep). It is always a good idea to use documented APIs to avoid issues like this.

Environment.SpecialFolder is a wrapper of [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) values, so it does not include flag for the default user profile or for another user.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are looking for such methods like:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Mydocuments);
```

as well as

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
Environment.SpecialFolder.System
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData
Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles
Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies
Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory
Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites
Environment.SpecialFolder.History
Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache
Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic
Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures
Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles
Environment.SpecialFolder.Programs
Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent
Environment.SpecialFolder.SendTo
Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu
```

And here what there are for: [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder)

Comment: Hi. No, the folders are listes above. I need the folders for "Default user" like described in screenshot.

Comment: The default user profile is used as the starting point for any new user. When a user logs on for the first time, Windows creates a new folder to store the new user's profile, and copies the default profile into that new folder. Changes that the user makes to the default profile are then recorded in the user's copy. The Default User profile is hidden by default.

Comment: This is part of the question. Please see above the question is bold: **Missed**. I am not asking for existing SpecialFolder stuff I already know, I want to complete the list with stuff of Windows system. The `Speical folder` list is not all the computer work with.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current user directory and the parent users directory using:

```
//get the current user's home directory (C:/Users/user)
string userDirectory = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%");
//get the Users directory (C:/Users)
string homeUsersDirectory = userDirectory.Substring(0, userDirectory.LastIndexOf("\\"));
```

Is this what you're looking for?
I'm not sure if it is possible to retrieve the user directory for other users. If you know their username you can get them by adding the username to the `homeUsersDirectory`string.
However by default you shouldn't have write permissions in their directories.

Comment: there are 5 red arrows in the screenshot. If you can describe for what the "Users/user" directory is, your answer would match the the last of the 5 red arrows as part answer.

Comment: Yes the "Users/user" directory is the directory for the current user (with username "user") so matches the last arrow in your screenshot. The "Users" directory is called "Benutzer" in your screenshot and contains all the user directories.

Comment: You can easily get to the Administrator and Default folders by adding the username to the Users directory: `string defaultDirectory = homeUsersDirectory + "\\Default";`
But as Sheng Jiang 蒋晟 said, you'll have to impersonate the Administrator to gain access to the folder.