# Access to the directory denied in C# - Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to access the Documents directory and sub-directories, but every time it says access denied. I see the Exception:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\My Music' is denied

Here is my code - all I am trying to do is get the total size of this directory.

```
class Program
{
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          try {
              // Make a reference to a directory.
              string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);              
              DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

              // Get a reference to each file in that directory.
              FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

              // Display the names and sizes of the files.
              Console.WriteLine("The directory {0} contains the following files:", di.Name);

              long size = 0;
              foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr)
              {
                  size += f.Length;
                  size++;
              }
              Console.WriteLine("The size of desktop files." + size);
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Exceptions {0}" , e);
          }         
      }    
}
```

Comment: Are you running this application off of a network drive? If so, try copying it to the desktop to see if the behaviour changes.

Comment: If you don't see it then you don't want to look into it with your code either.  This is a *hard link*, not a directory.  Use DirectoryInfo.Attributes, stay away from anything that has the System or ReparsePoint attribute.  Dragons live there.

Comment: Using that special folder might not be the best option for you here. Check out this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560884/windows-user-profile-path-folders

Comment: Hans nailed it. If you notice, it says "My Music". That's not the physical folder -- `C:\Users\YourName\Music`. None of the "My " folders are the physical ones. "My Music" = "Music", "My Videos" = "Videos", etc. You can see how the link changes by navigating to it in Explorer, then click in the address bar.

Comment: Also, since you're using the `AllDirectories`, there's no avoiding it. You may need to make a recursive function for the sub-directories so that you can skip those.

Comment: @HansPassant - If i use DirectoryInfo Attribute, how do i set the path to the documents of the current user? thats where I am stuck at.

Comment: You cannot use SearchOption.AllDirectories, you have to recurse the directory tree yourself.  Google "c# recurse directories" for lots of hits that show you how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather from skimming [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/access-denied-to-the-my-documents-and-settings/915eecc8-6a07-4d6a-8ca5-468ee51e9484) it could be that these folders are soft links provided for Windows backward compatibility.

For resolving the coding problem, you could make your own recursive folder search that ignores the exceptions thrown when the current user does not have access to a given folder.

Something like this perhaps:

```
    static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetAllFilesRecursive(string path)
    {
        var di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        var files = new List<FileInfo>();
        files.AddRange(di.GetFiles("."));

        foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            try
            {
                files.AddRange(GetAllFilesRecursive(directory));
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) // ignore directories which the user does not have access to
            {}

        }
        return files;
    }
```

Then rewrite your code to use the new function:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // Make a reference to a directory.
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            var fiArr = GetAllFilesRecursive(path);

            // Display the names and sizes of the files.
            Console.WriteLine("The directory {0} contains the following files:", path);

            long size = 0;
            foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr)
            {
                size += f.Length;
                size++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("The size of desktop files." + size);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exceptions {0}", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cool. Happy to help! Please remember to hit the check mark to the left of the answer to accept it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The search should be on TopDirectoryOnly and not on AllDirectories.

The problem is in this line:

`FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles(".", SearchOption.AllDirectories);`

Change it to:

`FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles(".", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);`

This should work.

Comment: That does work for the documents folder, but not for the sub-folders in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Some SpecialFolders needs specific Admin priviledges to run without any exception. You must run your code in Admin priviledges.

Comment: I did that too, but it would stuck to a folder that doesn't exist physically.